# Request.QueryString not returning the correct value

Tags: c#, url, query-string

I'm using AES encryption for the values of a URL. I've sampled it here with only one parameter to demonstrate the problem:

> http://localhost:12345/pagename?id=ha3bEv8A%2ffs0goPGeO6NPQ%3d%3d

`Request.QueryString["id"]` returns `"ha3bev8a/fs0gopgeo6npq=="` which clearly does not match the value of the encrypted ID.  Is something tripping up QueryString?

Comment: Have a look at `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode/Decode`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That (`"ha3bev8a/fs0gopgeo6npq==`) looks an awful lot like a Base64 encoded string

Comment: Are you using some built-in feature to encrypt/decrypt querystrings?  It looks like the value returned is just fine, and you need to additionally decrypt it yourself.

Comment: I can print the Encrypt and Decrypt methods here if need be?  If it doesn't match the value exactly it won't decrypt correctly right? It currently does not.  But if I manually copy the value in the URL and send that to the Decrypt method it works fine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a URL-encoded query string, which `Request.QueryString["id"]` seems to decode for you. You could always just re-encode it:

```
string decodedId = Request.QueryString["id"];
string reEncodedId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(decodedId);
```

Comment: No I need the decoded value! It's a 5 digit number resembling a zip code.  Rather I want the encoded value exactly so I can send it in to my decrypt method.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are seeing is in fact correct. What might be confusing you, is in the way it is presented. The id value in the URL is encoded in URL Encoding.
Some characters have to be encoded in the URL String in a different way, as they are special characters that sometimes can mess up the way the string is interpreted if they aren't encoded properly.

For example, in the query string you provided:
http://localhost:12345/pagename?id=ha3bEv8A%2ffs0goPGeO6NPQ%3d%3d

The %2f characters are a way to encode the '/' character, while %3d is a way to encode the '=' character.

When you get the value by getting Request.QueryString["id"] , it is decoding it back from an URL Encoded string to raw text.

Check this page for more reference.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Is there a way to grab the value as is and send to a method as a string?

Comment: Oh wait I can just encode it back to that value!  I have it now.